# Railties update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I tried to run `git push heroku` and the following error displayed

```
In Gemfile:

rails (= 3.2.3) depends on

  railties (= 3.2.3)

jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) depends on

  railties (3.2.5)
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.4.3.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'  
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
  gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

I changed my rails version to 3.2.5 did bundle update and bundle install. Still got the same problem hence I changed the rails version back to 3.2.3.

Answer (score -1):

Check Gemfile.lock and search which gem is requiring railties 3.2.5.

Also try to remove Gemfile.lock and run 'bundle install' again

Comment: @nilbus that's wrong. If you specify the gem versions, removing Gemfile.lock doesn't break anything. Also, if you have a decent test coverage, this is not an issue.

Comment: You're right. If you specify gem versions for everything (as this person did), removing the Gemfile.lock should be safe. I just worry, as most projects don't do that specify gem versions (that's a bad idea generally). Most projects don't have full coverage of interaction with gems either.

Comment: that's another matter. I usually specify gem versions (or at least, I know what I'm doing when not) and I write tests. Any other way is generally wrong from the mid-long term of a project lifecycle.

Comment: The gem versions get locked down in Gemfile.lock. Specifying them in the Gemfile renders bundle update <gemname> difficult and problematic when you need it, especially when you've specified specific versions of dependencies of another gem you want to update.

Comment: it is called "reproducible build". Specifying gem versions ensures that anyone can reproduce the same environment, even if Gemfile.lock  is removed for whatever reason. I haven't had problems in several years of doing so.

Comment: Why would you remove Gemfile.lock? That's its purpose (not Gemfile's), and it should be in version control.

Comment: because sometimes it happens to mess the dependency tree for gems. temporary removing the Gemfile.lock and regenerating it solves the problem. of course, Gemfile.lock is always under version control.
that said, here's my linkedin profile, in case you still doubt that I don't know what I'm saying: http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=4666998&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile

Answer (score -1):

Some days ago I face an issue something related to this.
What I done is

1. Removed Gemfile.lock
2. removed Versions of the gem from Gemfile
3. `Bundle install`

I usually don't use version in Gemfile unless it is necessary.

Comment: I did the following steps which I found from another stack overflow question 

Just do bundle install on your local prompt.
now place Gemfile.lock
git add .
git commit -m "commit message here"
git push
Now do git push heroku it should work.

This worked for me :)

Comment: It will be Great if you paste the link to that answer

Comment: Using `Git add .` is not a good method. Always try to specify the filename while you add.

Comment: Removing Gemfile.lock will cause all sorts of gems to get updated, often to versions that have breaking API changes that will cause your app to crash unexpectedly.